# when I use webpack function in undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use webpack in my simple project when create bundle javascript file and I am typing in console function. function undefined how prevent to undefined function 
in first js file

```
export default function read(){
    console.log("hello webpack");
}
```

and in main js file

```
import read from './def';

read();
```

and in console I look this error

```
VM51:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: read is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

in webpack config file

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Comment: Which console? The browser? Module code doesn't create global bindings. The function call in your main file should work.

Comment: you should show your simple project link in here, or we can not known what is your webpack config